A Quine program in C
From Wikipedia:

A quine is a computer program that takes no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output. The standard terms for these programs in the computability theory and computer science literature are "self-replicating programs", "self-reproducing programs", and "self-copying programs".
A quine is a fixed point of an execution environment, when that environment is viewed as a function transforming programs into their outputs. Quines are possible in any Turing-complete programming language, as a direct consequence of Kleene's recursion theorem. For amusement, programmers sometimes attempt to develop the shortest possible quine in any given programming language.

Code:
The code assumes ASCII.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    static constexpr char code[] = "#include <stdio.h>\n#include <stdlib.h>\n#include <string.h>\n\nint main(void)\n{\n    static constexpr char code[] = \"?\";\n\n    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof code - 1; ++i) {\n        if (code[i] == 63) {\n            for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof code - 1; ++j) {\n                switch(code[j]) {\n                    case '\\n': printf(\"\\\\n\");  break;\n                    case '\\\\': printf(\"\\\\\\\\\"); break;\n                    case '\"' : printf(\"\\\\\\\"\"); break;\n                    default  : printf(\"%c\", code[j]);\n                }\n            }\n        } else {\n            printf(\"%c\", code[i]);\n        }\n    }\n\n    return EXIT_SUCCESS;\n}\n";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof code - 1; ++i) {
        if (code[i] == 63) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof code - 1; ++j) {
                switch(code[j]) {
                    case '\n': printf("\\n");  break;
                    case '\\': printf("\\\\"); break;
                    case '"' : printf("\\\""); break;
                    default  : printf("%c", code[j]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            printf("%c", code[i]);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Test:
~/quine >> ./quine | diff quine.c -
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/quine >> 

no output, meaning success.
Review Request:
Anything. Everything.
Is there an easier way to do this with #embed? I heard LLVM Clang 19 has implemented it.

Edit: A quine that clones itself and runs some more quines is a follow-up to this question.

A few comments, mostly to shrink the source text size.

Recommend hex instead of decimal 63 (with a comment).
use minimal braces
no return
static constexpr may be "unnecessary verbiage" in this instance
don't repeat sizeof code - 1
putc() where possible
without return EXIT_SUCCESS;, which #include could vanish?
is <string.h> required???
pointers walking the string might be easier/briefer than array notation.


Choice of ? as pivotal character prevents use of C's ternary operator (that might stand in for switch() and a lot of case text...)

Suggest breaking long line/string into fragments (compiler will concatenate), then representing each fragment within itself... Another hill to climb...

"is <string.h> required???" ==> Not anymore, I was using strlen() on data previously, but forgot to remove it. I configured my editor to automatically include <stdlib.h>, and was too lazy to remove it too. :)

Why, we can even omit <stdio.h> and use the compiler's -include flag.

@Harith "New fangled!!" In my day, -I dirname was all that was available...

Clang replaces printf() with putchar() with -O1, and GCC with -O2. I changed the code albeit.

@Harith The reason for putc() is just its shorter name (and no format specifier)... Cheers! :-)

Fe2O3, Mildly disagree with some: the value of  "no return" (its a style issue), "don't repeat sizeof code - 1" (post suggested alternative), "putc() where possible" --> write for clarity as other code uses printf(), that is OK  to use printf("%c", code[i]); (A good compiler will emit efficient code either way, "is <string.h> required???" (excessive standard includes in a .c file are not a great concern.  IMHO, Code clarity trumps code golf.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Fair 'nuff. This project is a playful diversion for any experienced coder to try. Once it's working, and been revamped a few times, the novelty will fade and the project will be shelved... Shrinking code (avoiding 'cryptic') suggests another rainy day project to write bloated "quine" code in which every expression contributes to the objective (ie. no "do-nothing" statements/functions present just for the free sandwiches being served afterward...) Cheers! :-)

@Harith Now, write the code so that the binary "clones" itself (makes a replica with an altered filename.) Eg: "./don" will lead to both "don" and "dan" in the directory. Then "./dan" will add "den" to the folder. Use whatever criteria you can imagine. Eg: Change only one vowel/consonant, change two. Reverse the characters of the filename. Rot13 the filename. "Buy a vowel" to insert into the filename... Then write the "controller" that iteratively gathers all the existing filenames and executes all of them. Another "evolution" program has been created... :-) Cheers!

@Fe2O3 Seems intriguing enough for me to leave other things and implement it. How does the "controller" iteratively gathers all the exisiting filenames?

@Harith Maybe no "controller". Maybe each running instance "looks around" (scans directory), then randomly performs some random action, like cloning its disk image with an altered file name and running it, or deleting 1+ of its neighbours from disk, or committing (you'll like this) Hari Kari. (Add some sleep'ing to slow things down somewhat.) Occasionally, one instance spews the census of the folder to stdout... Population may grow and wain over time. Perhaps a 'maximum' population (carrying capacity) to not fill the disk or do it in a controlled sandbox. Dunno. Just for fun. Cheers! :-)

@Fe2O3 Did some think and ended up with this algorithm: https://godbolt.org/z/q61ejMens Might not be very interesting, but is amusing to me. Now it clones itself each time it is run. Next part would be writing the "controller". Feels like malware. :)

@Harith Interesting... Don't think of it as malware. Think of it as "Oompaloompas" or cute little "Minions" that propagate themselves. "Go forth and multiply," sayeth the Lord... :-) As long as we're having fun, and not hurting anyone. (In cyberspace, no one can hear you scream...) :-)

@Fe2O3 The program is finished. I have successfully fork-bombed myself (it took a minute or two to get the virtual machine under control.) My cute little minions are well and breeding. I will post it for review later. Thanks for the idea. :)
